# Uploading a .ZIP To Site

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

Using cPanel on Host Gator, I am trying to upload a .zip Extension.  However, anytime I try to upload this I get the errors:

```
JFolder::create: Could not create folder.Path: /home/packages
Warning: Failed to move file: /tmp/phpLHCUF0 to /home/packages/qi/SOURCES/tmp/com_rsform-v2.3.20.zip
```

I have verified that the folder `public_html/packages` on my server with `755` perms.  What am I missing here that is not uplaoding this file and installing?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your hosting provider to see if they can give any more information? Are you sure the directory has the correct ownership and group?

Comment: @Lodder - I'll reach out to the provider and see if they can give any further insight.  Directory does have proper ownership and group assignment

Comment: Please clarify in your question that you try to upload a package using Joomla admin install or you try to upload a package using cPanel file manager. This is not clear in your question... or you use cPanel for what? And if you use cPanel how does Joomla JFolder class/method come in the picture?

Comment: Also, please give info about why that packages folder should be in the root for Joomla, since for standardly installing an extension in Joomla you do not need that folder.